# Forbidden Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, api, microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to get shifts from a team.

```
 Error: MS-APP-ACTS-AS header needs to be set for application context requests
```

The flow process is as follows:

- Get oauth2 v2.0 token (Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta)
- Get "installedApps" and get the one with "Teams" on it. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-list?view=graph-rest-beta)
- Get ID from request above
- **Query for Shift** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/schedule?view=graph-rest-beta)

The error happens on the  last step.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http):

> Important: Application permissions are currently in private preview only and are not available for public use.

Comment: Correct and we are aware the documentation changes. I just want to be sure this is an issue that is not documented anywhere currently.